# How to set react in html using CDN Links or any other method in Vs Code and in Stack Overflow Snippets

Tags: reactjs

I intend to use react in html and render this code in a stack overflow snippet

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function ToDoForm(props) {
  const [input, setInput] = useState("");
  const handleChange = e =>{
    setInput(e.target.value);
  }
  const handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    props.onSubmit({
      id: Math.floor(Math.random() *10000),
      text:input
    })
  }

  return (
    <form className="todo-form" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Add a todo"
        value={input}
        name="text"
        className="todo-input"
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
      <button className='todo-button'>
        Add todo
      </button>
    </form>
  );
}

export default ToDoForm;
```

I attempted to use the CDN links on the website

Snippet of attempt

```
    <!Doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="uttf-8">
        <title>React! React! React!</title>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js" crossorigin></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" crossorigin></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.15.0/babel.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            ReactDOM.render(
//my code
               <form className="todo-form" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Add a todo"
        value={input}
        name="text"
        className="todo-input"
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
      <button className='todo-button'>
        Add todo
      </button>
    </form>
//my code
            );
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Yes, it did not work for me.

The todo app code is gotten from [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E1E08i2UJGI&t=703s)
Copy code from Time stamp 11:43 and everything before that

Comment: You're asking too many things at once, also you don't make it clear what your main problem is. 6 code snippets + a link to somewhere is just too much information. Keep it simple and then you might get answers.

Comment: [How do I create a React Stack Snippet with JSX support?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/338537/215552)

Comment: If you're asking how to use React in stacksnippets, add the CDN link to your HTML, and make sure to check the "Babel" option on the left sidebar.